# force:hasRecordId shows null in contoller method ?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:component controller="QuickContactController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" >
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.Lightning+'/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css'}"/>
   <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Contact" default="{'sobjectType':'contact'}"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    ...
```

Controller :

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) 
    {
        // Prepare the action to load account record

        alert(component.get("v.recordId"));
    }
)}
```

I got null. I hit the url with the right account id
https://instance/namespace/contactListApplication.app?ID=0017F000004PnrMQAS

I read [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/11/building-context-aware-lightning-components.html) that it inject the current page id to the attribute recordId. But I got null. Any Idea ? what I am missing here ? Please help me.

Comment: Record Id Only visiable for a sObject type 
Eg. 
`https://myapp--crm.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/sObject/003W000000QzKjcIAF/view`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Record Id Only visiable for a sObject type
Eg. `https://myapp--crm.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/sObject/‌​003W000000QzKjcIAF/v‌​iew`

**force:hasRecordId** will not work for a standalone app. (.app)

> You may integrate your component with **Contact** sObject using app
>   builder in order to use *RecordId*

Comment: +10 @Tariq Thanks . it works fine with lightning:actionOverride interface.

Comment: @bharath Enjoy buddy

Answer (score 1):

You should use: `?recordId=` instead of `?ID=`.
So here is your link: https://instance/namespace/contactListApplication.app?recordId=0017F000004PnrMQAS

Also here:

> The force:hasRecordId interface does two things to a component that
>   implements it. It adds an attribute named recordId to your component.
>   This attribute is of type String, and its value is an 18-character
>   Salesforce record ID, for example: 001xx000003DGSWAA4.  If you added
>   it yourself, the attribute definition would look like the following
>   markup:  `<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />`
>
> Note:  If your component implements force:hasRecordId, you don’t need
>   to add a recordId attribute to the component yourself. If you do add
>   it, **don’t change the access level or type of the attribute** or the
>   component will cause a runtime error.

So you should change recordId type definition.

Comment: I tried this also its null. Let me try with  @Tariq way

Comment: In a question you are showing code from component, but what is your <aura:application /> definition?